# Saturation and contrast settings for wine programs

Tags: compiz, nvidia, wine, settings, colors

I know that I can change contrast and saturation with nvidia-settings. How can I make different settings for different apps (i.e. wine) using nvidia-settings or any other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the option for this is in Compiz, namely brightness and contrast in Accessibility options. To get to it you need the CompizConfig Settings manager.

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Then type `ccsm` into run or terminal.

For individual wine programs, set the process name to the name of the `.exe` file (case sensitive), for example `WINWORD.exe` for Microsoft Word, or `FL.exe` for Fruity Loops.

Comment: no problem :) glad i could help